# Скрипт VBS запрет завершения процесса

Tags: vbscript, процесс

Как на VBScript обеспечить запрет завершения определённого процесса?

Замечание: процесс создаётся из программы, находящейся в той же папке, что и скрипт.

Comment: Для чего это надо? Может быть, необходимо просто не дать **закрыть** программу (то есть её главное окно)?

Comment: Единственный способ не дать завершить процесс — запустить его с привилегиями выше, чем у текущего пользователя (например, под учётной записью SYSTEM; под ней, кстати, работают службы). Но получить эти привилегии мало. Пользователь с административной учётной записью всё равно сможет завершить процесс, хотите ли вы того или нет. В свою очередь, выше администратора только драйвера.

Comment: @Arhad, ну, антивирусы умеют защищать свой процесс от любых посягательств :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, антивирусы свои драйвера устанавливают. И один из этих драйверов как раз и отвечает за самозащиту. Так что никакого противоречия с моими предыдущими комментариями.